# replace credentials with API Key when using Rally scripts

Tags: rally

So, I'm using the following Ruby scripts to make bulk changes to user permissions: https://github.com/RallyTools/Rally-User-Management

My issue is that I need to put this code on a server where other people might be able to access it, and I want to change the my_vars.rb file to hold my credentials in the form of an API key instead of my username and password.

Is this possible? Because it doesn't seem as simple as removing the username and password lines, and replacing those lines with one for an API key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rally_api gem's [documentation](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby) shows example of creating a connection with ApiKey in the [Usage](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby) section. The user management utility is based on this gem.

```
#Using api keys? -- currently rally1 only
Go to https://rally1.rallydev.com/login
You can generate an api key on this site and use it *instead* of username and password
config = {:base_url => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm"}
config[:api_key]   = "_your_api_key_from_https://rally1.rallydev.com/login"
config[:workspace]  = "Workspace Name"
config[:project]    = "Project Name"
config[:headers]    = headers #from RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new()
```

The commit history shows that rally_api started to support ApiKey authentication in version 1.0